# SAML2 Service Provider on non standard port behind a reverse proxy

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy, saml-2.0, python-social-auth

I have a SAML2 service provider ([Open edX Platform](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform) if it makes a difference), configured according to [docs](http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/named-release-cypress/configuration/tpa/index.html) and otherwise working normally. It runs at http://lms.local:8000 and works just fine with [TestShib](https://www.testshib.org/) test Identity Provider and other 3rd party providers.

Problems begin when nginx reverse proxy is introduced. The setup is as follows:

1. nginx, obviously, runs on port 80
2. LMS (the service provider) runs on port 8000
3. `lms.local` is aliased to localhost via hosts file

Nginx have the following site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name lms.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the following: python-social-auth detects that the server runs on `lms.local:8000` (via [`request.META['HTTP_PORT']`](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/strategies/django_strategy.py#L66)). So, if an attempt was made to use SAML SSO via the nginx proxy, it fails with the following message:

```
Authentication failed: SAML login failed: ['invalid_response'] (The response was received at http://lms.local:8000/auth/complete/tpa-saml/ instead of http://lms.local/auth/complete/tpa-saml/)
```

If that helps, an exception that causes this message is thrown in [python-saml.OneLogin_Saml2_Response.is_valid](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/blob/5a11b4a06d404568d9e56cd362c66857b36281f4/src/onelogin/saml2/response.py#L138).

The questions is: is that possible to run SP behind a reverse proxy on the same domain, but on different port? Shibboleth wiki says it is [totally possible](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/SPReverseProxy) to run a SP behind the reverse proxy on different domain, but says nothing about ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case reverse proxy was sending `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Port` headers, so I just modified django strategy to use those values instead of what Django provides (i.e. `request.get_host` and `request.META['SERVER_PORT']`), which yielded two pull requests:

- https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/pull/9848
- https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/741